# Setup one member MongoDB replica set

Tags: mongodb, replication

I want to [convert a standalone machine into one member replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/) by configuring the same in /etc/init.d/mongodb.

I came across the below command to do the same:

```
sudo mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /srv/mongodb/db0 --replSet rs0
```

But it's not working out. My mongo is configured to run on autostart.
I ran the following command to stop the running instance before running with the --replSet option.

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

Both commands above run without any output/error but when I run rs.initiate(), I get the error below:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetInitiate: undefined }",
    "code" : 13
}
```

From the error message it looks like the issue seems to be of access. Can anybody give any pointers?

Also, if I succeed with above command, will I need to make any changes to /etc/mongod.conf or /etc/init.d/mongodb so that the instance continues to run as a one node replica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: There are two ways of setting a mongod process's configuration; either (as in the command you found) as parameters on the command line, *or* in a configuration file mongod.conf. Your setup seems to be using a configuration file, so you need to [put the replica set settings in the mongod.conf file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#replication-options), *not* on the command line.

Secondly: to run the rs.initiate() command on a system where [authentication is enabled](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication/), as yours is, you must be authenticated as a user who has [permission to run this command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-built-in-roles/#cluster-administration-roles)